# Two layer network working in PyTorch, but cannot reproduce using pure linear algebra

Tags: classification, neural-networks, linear-algebra

Rewording the original question to comply with the CV topics.

I am trying to build a simple 2 layer network, and was going through the backprop mathematics of it, when I got stuck.

I am defining my network as follows:

\begin{cases}
(1)~H = X\cdot W_H^T + b_H \\
(2)~H_\text{ReLU} = \max{(0, H)} \\
(3)~Y = H_\text{ReLU}\cdot W_Y^T + b_Y \\
(4)~Y^{(i)}_\text{Softmax} = e^{Y_i}/\sum{e^{Y_j}} \\
(5)~\mathcal{L}(Y_\text{Softmax}, Y) = -\frac{1}{N}\sum{Y\ln{Y_\text{Softmax}}}
\end{cases}

with its backpropagation defined as

\begin{cases}{
(5, 4)~\partial{\mathcal{L}}/\partial{Y} = Y_{\text{Softmax},\cdot} - Y_{\text{Target},\cdot} \text{ (Already includes step 4)}\\
% (4)~\partial{Y_\text{Softmax}}/\partial{Y} = (Y(1-Y))^T\cdot \partial{\mathcal{L}}/\partial{Y_\text{Softmax}} \\
(3)~\begin{cases}
\partial{Y}/\partial{H_\text{ReLU}} = \partial{\mathcal{L}}/\partial{Y} \cdot W_Y^T \\
\partial{Y}/\partial{W_Y} = H^T_\text{ReLU}\cdot\partial{\mathcal{L}}/\partial{Y}\\
\partial{Y}/\partial{b_Y} = \partial{\mathcal{L}}/\partial{Y}
\end{cases} \\
(2)~\partial{H_\text{ReLU}}/\partial{H} = \partial{Y}/\partial{H_\text{ReLU}} \mathbb{1}_{\partial{Y}/\partial{H_\text{ReLU}} > 0} \\
(1)~\begin{cases}
\partial{H}/\partial{W_H} = X^T \cdot \partial{H_\text{ReLU}}/\partial{H} \\
\partial{H}/\partial{b_H} = \partial{H_\text{ReLU}}/\partial{H}
\end{cases}
}\end{cases}

However, I think I misunderstood how the cross-entropy loss + softmax and it's derivative work. When implementing the above equations, the training collapses to random.

If anyone could go through the math behind the backprop, and tell me if I am doing something wrong, I would really appreciate it.

**Original Question -- put on hold as off-topic**

I have a simple two layer network for MNIST classification written in PyTorch:

```py
network = nn.Sequential(
  nn.Linear(784, 512),
  nn.ReLU(),
  nn.Linear(512, 10),
)

epochs = 50
batch_size = 2048

learning_rate = 1e-2
momentum = 0.0  # Ignore momentum for simplicity

criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.SGD(network.parameters(), lr=learning_rate, momentum=momentum)
```

when training the above network, my training loss starts at 2.01, and drops to 0.28 after 50 epochs. The accuracy goes from 0.48 to 0.92.

Now I am trying to implement the same thing, but in numpy, and don't seem to get it. I understand that the numerics might differ, but my results are drastically different. I start with my cross entropy loss being 18.86 (!), which drops to 3.14 in 50 epochs. The accuracy starts at 0.29, peaks at 0.42 at 2nd-3rd epoch, and collapses after that to being random :'(. I suspect I didn't understand the cross-entropy loss and its derivative well, but I am not sure...

Below is the math that I tried deriving and the current implementation.

*Forward definition*:

\begin{cases}
(1)~H = X\cdot W_H^T + b_H \\
(2)~H_\text{ReLU} = \max{(0, H)} \\
(3)~Y = H_\text{ReLU}\cdot W_Y^T + b_Y \\
(4)~Y^{(i)}_\text{Softmax} = e^{Y_i}/\sum{e^{Y_j}} \\
(5)~\mathcal{L}(Y_\text{Softmax}, Y) = \text{Cross-Entropy Loss}
\end{cases}

*Backward definition*:

\begin{cases}{
(5, 4)~\partial{\mathcal{L}}/\partial{Y} = Y_{\text{Softmax},\cdot} - Y_{\text{Target},\cdot} \text{ (Already includes step 4)}\\
% (4)~\partial{Y_\text{Softmax}}/\partial{Y} = (Y(1-Y))^T\cdot \partial{\mathcal{L}}/\partial{Y_\text{Softmax}} \\
(3)~\begin{cases}
\partial{Y}/\partial{H_\text{ReLU}} = \partial{\mathcal{L}}/\partial{Y} \cdot W_Y^T \\
\partial{Y}/\partial{W_Y} = H^T_\text{ReLU}\cdot\partial{\mathcal{L}}/\partial{Y}\\
\partial{Y}/\partial{b_Y} = \partial{\mathcal{L}}/\partial{Y}
\end{cases} \\
(2)~\partial{H_\text{ReLU}}/\partial{H} = \partial{Y}/\partial{H_\text{ReLU}} \mathbb{1}_{\partial{Y}/\partial{H_\text{ReLU}} > 0} \\
(1)~\begin{cases}
\partial{H}/\partial{W_H} = X^T \cdot \partial{H_\text{ReLU}}/\partial{H} \\
\partial{H}/\partial{b_H} = \partial{H_\text{ReLU}}/\partial{H}
\end{cases}
}\end{cases}

**Support functions**:

```py
def Initialize(fan_in, dims):
  rand_mat = np.random.random(dims)
  k = np.sqrt(1.0 / fan_in)
  return 2 * k * rand_mat - k

def Softmax(x):
  exps = np.exp(x - np.max(x, axis=1).reshape(-1, 1))
  return exps / np.sum(exps, axis=1).reshape(-1, 1)

def CrossEntropyLoss(y_hat, y, epsilon=1e-12):
  y_hat = np.clip(y_hat, epsilon, 1.0)
  return -np.sum(y * np.log(y_hat), axis=1).mean()

def CrossEntropyLossGrad(y_hat, y):
  return (y_hat - y) / y.shape[0]

def Accuracy(y_hat, y):
  y_hat_decode = y_hat.argmax(axis=1)
  y_decode = y.argmax(axis=1)
  return np.mean(y_hat_decode == y_decode)
```

**Initializations**:

```py
D_in = 28*28
D_H = 512
D_Y = 10

w_h = Initialize(D_in, (D_H, D_in))
b_h = Initialize(D_in, (D_H,))
w_y = Initialize(D_H, (D_Y, D_H))
b_y = Initialize(D_H, (D_Y,))
```

**Training routine**:

```py
# train_features and train_targets are the flattened images and one-hot encoded labels.

learning_rate = 1e-2
epochs = 50
batch_size = 2048

max_accuracy = 0

for epoch in range(epochs):
  idx = 0
  running_loss = 0.0
  running_accuracy = 0.0
  while idx < len(train_features):
    x_train = train_features[idx:idx+batch_size]
    y_train = train_targets[idx:idx+batch_size]
    idx += batch_size

    # Forward prop
    h = x_train.dot(w_h.T) + b_h                 # (1)
    h_relu = np.maximum(h, 0)                    # (2)
    y = h_relu.dot(w_y.T) + b_y                  # (3)
    y_softmax = Softmax(y)                       # (4)
    loss = CrossEntropyLoss(y_softmax, y_train)  # (5)
    accuracy = Accuracy(y_softmax, y_train)

    # Backprop
    grad_y = CrossEntropyLossGrad(y_softmax, y_train)   # (5, 4)
    grad_h_relu = grad_y.dot(w_y)                       # (3)
    grad_w_y = grad_y.T.dot(h_relu)                     # (3)
    grad_b_y = grad_y.mean(axis=0)                      # (3)
    grad_h = grad_h_relu.copy()                         # (2)
    grad_h[grad_h<0] = 0.0                              # (2)
    grad_w_h = grad_h.T.dot(x_train)                    # (1)
    grad_b_h = grad_h.mean(axis=0)                      # (1)

    # Update
    w_h -= learning_rate * grad_w_h
    b_h -= learning_rate * grad_b_h
    w_y -= learning_rate * grad_w_y
    b_y -= learning_rate * grad_b_y

    fraction_of_data = len(x_train) / len(train_features)
    running_loss += loss * fraction_of_data
    running_accuracy += Accuracy(y_softmax, y_train) * fraction_of_data

  print("{}/{} Loss: {:.2f}, Acc: {:.2f}".format(epoch+1, epochs, running_loss, running_accuracy), end="")
  if running_accuracy > max_accuracy:
    best_y = y_softmax
    max_accuracy = running_accuracy
    print(" *")
  else:
    print()
```

**Update 1**: After changing the initialization to Kaiming, the training starts at a reasonable loss of 2.28, but still collapses to random after ~5-7 epochs

Comment: your initialization looks off. if it's done correctly, then at least the initial loss should be around $\ln 10$.

Comment: Changed the initialization -- it helped with starting around ~ln10. But training still collapses.